# PageSpeed Insights not seeing the Gzip compression

Tags: seo, compression, gzip

I'm trying to speed up my website. Google insights (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) tells me that a critical problem is to enable GZip compression.

The address of the site is http://user2.net
It's based on codeigniter framework.

I have enabled gzip compression with folowing changes to my .htaccess file:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript


<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

I have tested the site with this tool:
http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php
It says that gzip is enabled.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe gzip was already enabled before, so you wouldn't see any change.

Comment: As Mark suggests, find out if GZIP compression was enabled beforehand. http://checkgzipcompression.com/ Google Page Speed also tells me I need to enable it, but it is already enabled!

Answer (score 14):

Did you try these lines in your .htaccess?

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

It works for my site.

Answer (score 9):

First, check if gzip is enable in your server. You can use this tool: 
http://checkgzipcompression.com/

If it's ok, then, check that the compression is working FOR ALL your files.
If Google Page Speed Test found on single file without GZIP compression from your server, the website with fail the test.

You can use Google Chrome for this:

1. Inspect your code; in the image you can see there is Content Encoding GZIP for the html file.
   [image]
2. Clic on every file and find which doesn't have the GZIP encode; maybe the CSS type o JS type.
3. When you find it, add the file type to your gzip.conf

This is the simple configuration for gzip.conf

```
gzip on;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\\.(?!.*SV1)";
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/javascript text/xml application/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml application/xml+rss image/x-icon image/svg+xml image/jpeg image/jpg image/png
gzip_vary on;
```

Good Luck!

Comment: That can indeed differ per file type. On my site, all file types that I listed in the .htaccess file are gzipped, except the javascript files. (Of course, I listed that type as well.)

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to enable gzip compression - 
 By configuring server settings

For apache -

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

For nginx

```
gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";
gzip_vary on;
```

And by editing `.htaccess` as shown above

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Source: [Enable compression](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's the redirect, it sets 2 headers

first 301 (or 302, didn't check)

second 200 + gzip

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may be having an "Uncompressed Pages" issue after running a SEMRush site audit, try adding the following to your .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html|txt|css|js|php)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_Gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Always remember to backup your .htaccess file before making any edits, as a simple typing error could cause certain features of your website to fail or even worse - break your entire website.

Reference: https://www.semrush.com/blog/improve-page-load-times-htaccess-file/

Answer (score -2):

Google has addressed this exact same concern in their FAQ as  why would you get the errors to compress/gzip your files.

Checkout from Google's Insights:
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/EnableCompression#FAQ

Earlier they used to have a chome extension but now it has been removed so they point you to https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ where when you enter any url, they tell which particular files or scripts are still eligible for compression or blocking the page render or both.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @PaulRoub thank you for your feedback. I am currently new to answering questions. Just updated my answer. Hope that helps. Thanks.