# Confusion about gzip, is it compressed or not?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, gzip

Sorry to bother you with a question that seems very well documented, but none of the things I tried was completely satisfying.

My Company switched from a hosting package to a manages Server just last week and I'm still in the process of optimising it.

Now, Googles PageSpeed Insights tell me, [it is not compressed](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=praxisprint.de), as does [GTMetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.praxisprint.de/uEp56ZAP). [GidNetwork](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php) tells me compression works fine.

I have already added

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

to my .htaccess, (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744652/pagespeed-insights-not-seeing-the-gzip-compression)) which works correctly, other settings I've changed are fine, as well as

```
zlib.output_compression = On
```

to my php.ini.
The entire .htaccess and php.ini can be seen at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QMw9n/).

Headers sent and received in both Firefox and Chrome claim that compression is happening.

I also created a [httpd.conf](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/speed-up-apache-20-web-access-or-downloads-with-mod_deflate.html) in my home directory, because none existed on my server yet. Should I move the file somewhere else?

**What I really want to know:**

Soo... what am I doing wrong? Is it compressed? Is it not? How can I make google 'see' the compression?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me in the end to compress the js/css files that were left uncompressed for reasons I don't quite get yet is described [here](http://www.warpconduit.net/2010/10/23/enabling-gzip-compression-of-php-css-and-js-files-without-mod_deflate/).

In this method, javascript and css-files are forcibly gzipped by a php-script. It also sets new "Expire"-Headers, so if you want caching for more than 5 Minutes, change the number. Adding different files is trickier, but possible, I think.

Answer (score 2):

This should be the function you need, it should automatically generates the headers you need:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php

anyway check your php version because it works only with php 5.4.0 or later ones.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I'll propably won't be able to use this, since we're using an outdated CMS (which I'm tasked to replace after I've optimsed it as far as possible), but how would I go about using this anyway? Would I wrap the entire html-generating file with the function? Thank you very much for the suggestions though.

Comment: you can look the exemple number 5 on the link i posted, there you find a simple way to use it.

About your CMS, this maybe the time to speed up the conversion :) good luck for your duties!

Answer (score 1):

Although my browser accepts deflate/gzip encoding (`Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate`), your server does not answer using compressed data:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 11 Mar 2014 09:41:45 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=200
Etag: "96-100e9-4f4517d791912"
Expires: Fri, 11 Apr 2014 13:28:25 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=2692000, public
Vary: User-Agent
```

If it was compressed, the server would send also

```
Content-Encoding:   deflate
```

Use FireBug or the dev console to see the headers. It must be your httpd.conf.
You cannot simply create this file in your home directory and Apache will load it.

Have a look in `/etc/apache*` and `/etc/httpd/*` for config files.

Comment: It sends Content-Encoding:"gzip" for the main html file, though not for all js/css files...
The weird thing is, the /etc/httpd folder doesn't exist on my server, I do have /etc/apache-ssl and /apache-dav, but -dav is empty and -ssl is read-blocked for me... 
Could I create the directoty /httpd/ or is it a severe sign that something is wrong that it's missing at all?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @KjeldSchmidt Google complains about js/css not beeing compressed. I'd ask your server administrator/provider for the correct locations of config files and how to include your own. You cannot simply create a directory.. in the main Apache config there must be `Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/*` or something

Answer (score 1):

You have already enabled gzip compression but you haven't set it to compress some file types such as javascript and css. That is why Googles PageSpeed was tried to suggest to enable compression. To enble compression for those two types, use

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
```

Comment: Right, only .js and .css-files are still uncompressed, but I already had these lines in my .htaccess =/ *scratches his head*